# Respuesta Json Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, json, api, restful, validación

tengo una duda con respecto a retornar una respuesta en json para una api que estoy haciendo en laravel... Resulta que uso mi metodo de validacion dentro del controlador pero no he podido hacer posible que frene el sistema si la validacion no es pasada, lo que hace inmediatamente es redirigir al home.. anexo Mi controlador con las funciones

```
App\User;
App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $validate = Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',

        ]);

           if ($validate->fails()) { 
           return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422) 
            } 


    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'status_user' => $data['status_user'],
        ]);


    }

    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
    $user->generateToken();

    return response()->json(['data' => $user->toArray()], 201);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {


    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();





   event(new registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    // After the user is created, he's logged in.
    $this->guard()->login($user);


    return $this->registered($request, $user)
     ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }




}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizas el registro de Laravel? Veo que intentas reinventar la rueda.

Comment: porque quiero hacer unas validaciones como que confirme el password y consulte el correo pero no logro que me devuelva ese error en json

Comment: ¿Al menos está generando los errores la validación?

Comment: no me retorna nada... me manda de una a la pagina por defecto de laravel

Answer (score 0):

Listo... Solo debí editar esta funcion en `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions`

```
protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
    {
        if ($e->response) {
            return $e->response;
        }

        $errors = $e->validator->errors()->getMessages();

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput(
            $request->input()
        )->withErrors($errors);
    }
```

POR ESTA

```
protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
    {
        $errors = $e->validator->errors()->getMessages();


        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }
```